# Is there a way that a table view pops up when i select a row in a table?

Tags: iphone, tableview

Is there a way that a `UITableView` pops up when i select a `row` in a `table`?

thanks in advance.

Comment: i dont want to navigate to the other view.....                                it should be like how we get a table view when new wifi hot spots are detected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `UITableView` delegate method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:myView];
}
```

Here, myView is the view which you have `IBOutlet`.

like

in .h file

```
IBOutlet UIView *myView;
```

Let me know in case of any difficulty.

Cheers.

Comment: but can u tell how i can use cellForRowAtIndexPath: method for inner table view

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way on row selection method you have to fire up a method which creates auiview smaller in size as desired and in that view table view as subview.
Plz specify what type or kind of pop-up you want to appear.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I understand now.

You should use table view's updating methods:

```
[myTableView beginUpdates];
NSArray *indexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1],
                         [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:1],
                         [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:1],
                         [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:1],nil];
[myTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
[myTableView endUpdates];
```